# How to get adress of last non empty cell in a excel using MACROS(VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get the cell address of the last non empty cell within an excel sheet. Basically I want the row and column number/name of the last non empty cell. I have found few ansers to find out the value in the last non empty cell but I need cell adress not contents.

Comment: What is the definition of "last"?

Comment: Suppose there is a table from A1 to D4 and below that there is no cell in excel with a value below that, then D4 will be last non empty cell. If there is some value at Z44 below the table, then the last non empty cell will be Z44. I want to get this Z44 using macros

Comment: From what you say, you already know where the cell is, so just instead of `range().value`, use `range().address`. and next time show the code you already have

Answer (score 3):

For data like:

[image: xsdew]

Most people would like to find the *Blue* cell:

```
Sub FindBlue()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows)
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

If you want the *Yellow* cell then:

```
Sub FindYellow()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByColumns)
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I get row name and column name searately in both the functions?   I want C and 14 separately from FindBlue and E and 7 separately using FindYellow