# Find first non-empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hey everyone I've been trying to figure this one out, but I can't seem to get it to work. It probably has a really simple answer though.

So this has to be done as a macro because it is a part of a much larger program.

What I am trying to do is find a cell that has any value in it. Meaning it can be any word, number, or symbol. Non-blank if you will.

This is what I am currently using:

> Column D
>   1
>   (blank)
>   (blank)
>   123

Macro:

```
Columns("D").Find("*", Cells(Rows.Count, "D")).Select
```

and what is happening is that it loops back skipping the two blanks and the 123 then goes back to the 1.

Any help would be appreciated and if there are other suggestions they would be welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get adress of last non empty cell in a excel using MACROS(VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078009/how-to-get-adress-of-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-excel-using-macrosvba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look by `xlByRows` from the last cell in Column D, and then use `xlNext`, ie

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Columns("D").Find("*", Cells(Rows.Count, "D"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlNext)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It got me where I needed to go. I forgot to mention that I needed that specific cell to be selected so I just made a simple change:   
    Dim rng1 As Range Set 
    rng1 = Columns("D").Find("*", ActiveCell, xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlNext) 
    rng1.Select 

Also thank you for fixing my original post.